# Get the directory in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get the "C:\WINDOWs" path if the operating system is on the another drive then "E:\WINDOWS".
I used getenv("windir"), but i dont want this solution. what if i change the name of my environment variable.variable

Comment: If you change the name of windir, all Windows applications (including Office) won't work properly anymore.

Comment: Quandary - Either way the API Microsoft provided should be used instead, getenv("windir") is from Windows 3.11 days and is kept around for legacy stuff like batch files.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what do you need the windir path for?

Answer (score 3):

See windows API `GetWindowsDirectory`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yes i used the same function, but how to convert TCHAR to std::string.

Answer (score 0):

The API [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing in [CSLID_WINDOWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) looks like what you need.